# jQuery não retorna valor

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

```js
  function checkRadioPeriodo() {
  
       if ( $("[name='periodo']").val() == undefined ) {
   
          alert("Escolha um período!");
          return false;

       }

    }
    
    $("#botao").on ("click", function () {
          checkRadioPeriodo();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="periodo" value="semanal" /> Semanal 
<input type="radio" name="periodo" value="mensal" /> Mensal 
<br />
<button id="botao"> Validar </button>
```

Por que não funciona?

**Obs**.: A validação pelo **name** e não pelo **id** é necessária aqui.

Comment: Porque você não coloca simplesmente checked em um dos radios?

Comment: Qual a finalidade da verificação? Não ficou bem claro na sua pergunta.

Comment: @santOwill, Só respondendo. é um rádio button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não funciona porque há um erro de lógica aí. Ao usar `$("[name='periodo']").val()` você está pegando o valor do primeiro elemento `name='periodo'` que houver na página, que no caso é `semanal`.

Logo, `$("[name='periodo']").val()` não é igual a `undefined`, é igual a `semanal`, portanto não satisfaz a condição do `if`.

O que deve fazer é apenas acrescentar `:checked` ao seletor, pois assim irá retornar o valor do radio checado, e se nenhum estiver checado, aí sim será `undefined`:

```js
function checkRadioPeriodo() {

   if ( $("[name='periodo']:checked").val() == undefined ) {

      alert("Escolha um período!");
      return false;

   }

}

$("#botao").on ("click", function () {
   checkRadioPeriodo();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="periodo" value="semanal" /> Semanal 
<input type="radio" name="periodo" value="mensal" /> Mensal 
<br />
<button id="botao"> Validar </button>
```

Você também pode verificar se é *false*, sem precisar comparar com `undefined`. Basta colocar um sinal de `!` antes do seletor jQuery:

```
if ( !$("[name='periodo']:checked").val() ) {
```

O sinal de `!` irá invalidar se o valor for *vazio*, *undefined* ou `0` (tipo numérico).

Outra forma também é utilizando `.length` para retornar quantos radios foram marcados. Se retornar `0` (nenhum foi marcado), irá invalidar:

```
if ( !$("[name='periodo']:checked").length ) { // com !
```

ou

```
if ( $("[name='periodo']:checked").length === 0 ) { // sem !
```

Comment: essa é a resposta que eu queria: sintética e completa. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro sua intenção com o código.

Mas tente isso, pelo que entendi vc quer verificar se alguma das opções foi selecionada:

```js
function checkRadioPeriodo() {
  let $periodos = $('input:radio[name=periodo]');

  if($periodos.is(':checked') === false) {
    alert("Escolha um período!");
  }
}

    
$("#botao").on("click", function () {
 checkRadioPeriodo();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="periodo" value="semanal" /> Semanal 
<input type="radio" name="periodo" value="mensal" /> Mensal 
<br />
<button id="botao">Validar</button>
```

Bom é isso. Lembrando que com javascript puro vc faz tudo isso sem muitas dificuldades também.

Comment: a negativa é assim: !$("[name='periodo']").is(':checked') ?

Comment: $periodos.is(':checked') === true // pra verificar se está checado


$periodos.is(':checked') === false // pra verificar se não está checado

Answer (score 0):

É melhor testar se o elemento está checado.
use essa versão da função no sua footer:

```
function checkRadioPeriodo() {          
       if ( $('input[name="periodo"]').is(':checked') ) {               
          console.log("checado!");
          return false;
       }else{
        console.log("Não selecionado!");
          return false;
       }
    }       
    $("#botao").on("click", function (){
        checkRadioPeriodo();
    });
```

Comment: a negativa é assim: !$("[name='periodo']").is(':checked') ?

Comment: A negativa correta é: `!( $('input[name="periodo"]').is(':checked') )`, pois dessa forma  checa-se o retorno de is().

Answer (score -1):

Eu não entendi muito bem o que você quer, mas vou tentar ajudar mesmo assim.
Você só está retornando algo quando não seleciona nenhum dos dois... faça assim:

```js
  function checkRadioPeriodo() {
  
       if ( $("[name='periodo']").val() == undefined ) {
   
          alert("Escolha um período!");
          return false;

       }else{
         return $("[name='periodo']").val();
       }

    }
    
    $("#botao").on ("click", function () {
          checkRadioPeriodo();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="periodo" value="semanal" /> Semanal 
<input type="radio" name="periodo" value="mensal" /> Mensal 
<br />
<button id="botao"> Validar </button>
```